# convert user input as hexadecimal value

Tags: c

I saw a function which convert an array of char into binary value and keep the correct order.
For instance `F1` will be converted as `1111 0001`.

```
int hex_to_bin(char hex) {
       if (hex >= '0' && hex <= '9') {
           return hex - '0';
       } else if (hex >= 'a' && hex <= 'f') {
           return hex - 'a' + 10;
       } else if (hex >= 'A' && hex <= 'F') {
           return hex - 'A' + 10;
       } else {
           printf("Invalid hexadecimal character: %c\n", hex);
           exit(1);
      }
  }


 void hex_to_bin_array(char* hex_values, int gpio_count, int* bin_array) {
      printf("Binary values: ");
      for (int i = 0; i < gpio_count; ++i) {
          // Calculate the binary value from the hexadecimal input
          int gpio_value = hex_to_bin(hex_values[i / 4]) >> (3 - i % 4) & 1;
          bin_array[i] = gpio_value;
          printf("%d", gpio_value);
          if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0) {
              printf(" ");
          }
      }
      printf("\n");
  }
```

However I don't understand the algorithm. For `i ∈ [0;4[` value will be respectively shifted by `1,0,1,0`. Obviously I am doing a mistake in the previous reasoning but I can not figure out what is it.

Comment: This algorithm hurts my eyes.

Comment: Why ? What would you do differently ? @ams

Comment: @void_brain Maybe something like this would be more readable: https://godbolt.org/z/3E9j5daMa (and faster, and more portable).

Comment: @void_brain basically don't call `hex_to_bin` 4 times for every digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For `i ∈ [0;4[` value will be respectively shifted by `1,0,1,0`.

`&` has lower precedence than `>>`. `x >> (3 - i % 4) & 1` is `(x >> (3 - i % 4)) & 1`. For `i` = 0, 1, 2, and 3, this shifts by 3, 2, 1, and 0, respectively. The `& 1` is applied to the result of the shift, not to the amount to shift.